# Rails date string deserialized wrong format

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, date

Using xdan's datetimepicker as such:

```
config.datetime_picker_default_options = {
    timepicker: false,
    format: 'm-d-Y',
  }

  # Set DateTimePickerInput input format. This if for backend (Ruby)
  config.datetime_picker_input_format = "%m-%d-%Y"
```

I'm getting a perfect string in my object (upper right of pic) but when it comes to the SQL Update statement, it's getting reformatted incorrectly (bottom left)

[image: DatePicker]

Here's the datetimepicker with its formatting (m-d-y)
[Datepickerformat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5x8xO.png)

But when it hits SQL database, it's recorded as:
2021-06-04 00:00:00.000

So you can see that day and month are backwards.

I've tried adding a new initializer, and reformatting the serialize () in connection_adapters > sqlserver > type > date.rb:

```
module ActiveRecord
  module ConnectionAdapters
    module SQLServer
      module Type
        class Date < ActiveRecord::Type::Date
          def sqlserver_type
            "date"
          end

          def serialize(value)
            return unless value.present?

            date = super(value).to_s(:_sqlserver_dateformat)
            Data.new date, self
          end

          def deserialize(value)
            value.is_a?(Data) ? super(value.value) : super
          end

          def type_cast_for_schema(value)
            serialize(value).quoted
          end

          def quoted(value)
            Utils.quote_string_single(value)
          end

          private

          def fast_string_to_date(string)
            ::Date.strptime(string, fast_string_to_date_format)
          rescue ArgumentError
            super
          end

          def fast_string_to_date_format
            ::Date::DATE_FORMATS[:_sqlserver_dateformat]
          end
```

But no matter what, it consistently flips month and day.

Comment: Pictures are not the best tool for showing your issue -- especially in this case. Show the expected and actual results in text.

Comment: Why aren't you using the attributes api for that? https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Attributes/ClassMethods.html

Comment: @Joel_Blum that would probably work if I could customize it, but not ideal because that's kind of a medium level fix, I have 75-ish models and hundreds of datetime picker fields, need a global fix somewhere around the SQL Adapter level

Answer (score 1):

If you save value to a datetime column of your database like Postgres, it will fix the value to a format type (eg "2021-05-12 00:00:00.000000").
But if you change that column to string type, you can save it as any value (eg with "05-12-2021" like you want).
So the simple and fast solution is change column from datetime to string.
Hope this idea can help your problem, my friend !: D